# filter table based on join but select all joins without taking filter into account

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, typeorm

I have the following query generated with the Typeorm querybuilder

Current behavior:
Right now what is happening is that marines are correctly filtered but selected joins are also filtered by the given condition. returning only the dock that matches the condition instead of all the docks that belong to the marine.

Desired result:
I want to obtain all marines that have at least one dock whose name is 'dock 1'. And I want to include all docks belonging to that marine without taking their name into account.

How should i execute this query?

Any help would be much appreciated.

mariadb  Ver 15.1

typeorm@0.2.37

```
SELECT `c`.`id`                AS `c_id`,
       `c`.`name`              AS `c_name`,
       `c`.`description`       AS `c_description`,
       `c`.`FkId`              AS `c_FkId`,
       `c`.`FkModel`           AS `c_FkModel`,
       `c`.`isActive`          AS `c_isActive`,
       `c`.`createdAt`         AS `c_createdAt`,
       `c`.`updatedAt`         AS `c_updatedAt`,
       `c`.`phones`            AS `c_phones`,
       `c`.`emails`            AS `c_emails`,
       `c`.`mainImage`         AS `c_mainImage`,
       `c`.`galleryImages`     AS `c_galleryImages`,
       `c`.`addressDetailsId`  AS `c_addressDetailsId`,
       `c_Docks`.`id`          AS `c_Docks_id`,
       `c_Docks`.`name`        AS `c_Docks_name`,
       `c_Docks`.`description` AS `c_Docks_description`,
       `c_Docks`.`FkId`        AS `c_Docks_FkId`,
       `c_Docks`.`FkModel`     AS `c_Docks_FkModel`,
       `c_Docks`.`isActive`    AS `c_Docks_isActive`,
       `c_Docks`.`createdAt`   AS `c_Docks_createdAt`,
       `c_Docks`.`updatedAt`   AS `c_Docks_updatedAt`,
       `c_Docks`.`MarineId`    AS `c_Docks_MarineId`
FROM `marine` `c`
         LEFT JOIN `dock` `c_Docks` ON `c_Docks`.`MarineId` = `c`.`id`
WHERE `c`.`isActive` = true
  AND (`c_Docks`.`name` = 'dock 1')
# ORDER BY c_id DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Filter out all the rows relevant from table marine:
select  from marine C where `c`.`isActive` = true
Step 2: Make the earlier SQL an inline view and left join it with table dock and apply the filter on dock table.
So, the SQL should look like this:

```
SELECT          c.<column_names> ,
                c_docks.<column_names>
FROM            (
                       SELECT <column_names>
                       FROM   marine
                       WHERE  isActive = true) c
LEFT OUTER JOIN dock c_docks
ON              c.id = c_docks.marine_id
AND             c_docks.NAME = 'dock 1';
```

Comment: thanks a lot it's pretty close to what I wanted.

Comment: Why use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?

Answer (score 1):

You can join with `dock` twice. Once to filter on the dock name, and another time to get all docks.

```
SELECT `c`.`id`                AS `c_id`,
       `c`.`name`              AS `c_name`,
       `c`.`description`       AS `c_description`,
       `c`.`FkId`              AS `c_FkId`,
       `c`.`FkModel`           AS `c_FkModel`,
       `c`.`isActive`          AS `c_isActive`,
       `c`.`createdAt`         AS `c_createdAt`,
       `c`.`updatedAt`         AS `c_updatedAt`,
       `c`.`phones`            AS `c_phones`,
       `c`.`emails`            AS `c_emails`,
       `c`.`mainImage`         AS `c_mainImage`,
       `c`.`galleryImages`     AS `c_galleryImages`,
       `c`.`addressDetailsId`  AS `c_addressDetailsId`,
       `c_Docks`.`id`          AS `c_Docks_id`,
       `c_Docks`.`name`        AS `c_Docks_name`,
       `c_Docks`.`description` AS `c_Docks_description`,
       `c_Docks`.`FkId`        AS `c_Docks_FkId`,
       `c_Docks`.`FkModel`     AS `c_Docks_FkModel`,
       `c_Docks`.`isActive`    AS `c_Docks_isActive`,
       `c_Docks`.`createdAt`   AS `c_Docks_createdAt`,
       `c_Docks`.`updatedAt`   AS `c_Docks_updatedAt`,
       `c_Docks`.`MarineId`    AS `c_Docks_MarineId`
FROM `marine` `c`
JOIN `dock` `c_Docks` ON `c_Docks`.`MarineId` = `c`.`id`
JOIN `dock` `dock_1` ON `dock_1`.`MarineId` = `c`.`id`
WHERE `c`.`isActive` = true
  AND `dock_1`.`name` = 'dock 1'
```

There's no reason to use `LEFT JOIN` here, since you don't want to include marines with no matching `dock`.

Comment: how does this compare in terms of performance to the other solution

Comment: this query is dynamically generated by a request, in this case the filter and joined relation are the same but it is not always the case. I do want to include marines even if the don't have a matching dock.

Comment: It should be better because `INNER JOIN` is usually faster than `OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: You wrote "I want to obtain all marines that have at least one dock whose name is 'dock 1'" How can they have at least one dock with that name if they don't have any matching docks?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain myself well. A part of the request I process is filtering an entity based on some criteria, and the second part is joining requested relations. This question is based on the scenario where this two tasks conflict with each other. I do use an inner join for filtering but not for loading requested relations.